# SQL Server : Group, create columns and sort by week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a table with score from a football team. These scores (in percentage) are already sorted according to the week by player per week. Timestamp are already converted and there is now multiples score for one player per week as following:

```
    Week       Player       Score
  2013w51      Louis         12
  2013w51      Miguel        76
  2013w51      Miguel        21
  2013w51     Charles        62
  2013w52      Pedro         21
  2013w52     Rodriguo       62
     .           .           .
     .           .           .
     .           .           .
  2014w2       Louis         52
  2014w2       Louis         85
  2014w2      Charles        65
```

I would like to sort by player the average score per week and per player (grand total) as following (considering that Week is fixed for 9 weeks):

```
  Player      2013w51  2013w52  2014w1  2014w2 ...
  Louis          14        58      62     68.5  ...
  Miguel         48.5      62      48      66   ...
  Charles        65        12      89      56   ...
  Pedro          82        85      54      76   ...
  Rodriguo       16        56      76      29   ...
```

Thank you for your kind help

Tdev

EDIT:

I used PIVOT function as following.

```
    SELECT  *
        FROM
        ( SELECT [Player], [Week], [Score]
            FROM    Temp_Db) AS SourceTable
        PIVOT
        (
            AVG([Average])
            FOR [Week] IN ([2013w51], [2013w52], [2014w1], [2014w2])
        ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: You should do this in application level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PIVOT function as following.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM
    ( SELECT [Player], [Week], [Score]
        FROM    Temp_Db) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        AVG([Average])
        FOR [Week] IN ([2013w51], [2013w52], [2014w1], [2014w2])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @T table (week1 varchar(50), player varchar(50), score int)

insert into @T values ('2013w51', 'Louis', 12)

insert into @T values ('2013w51', 'Louis', 50)

insert into @T values ('2013w51', 'Louis', 13)

insert into @T values ('2013w5', 'Pedro', 22)

insert into @T values ('2013w51', 'Louis', 50)

insert into @T values ('2013w5', 'Pedro', 13)

select week1,player,AVG(score) as ColValue from @T

group by week1,player

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I didn't well explain my problem. I found the solution (the edit in OP)